# line.open() error when generating an audible sine wave on Macbook Pro

Tags: java, audio, runtime-error, synthesizer

I have this code here that I have from a tutorial on how to create an audible sine wave:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;


public class FixedFreqSine {

   //This is just an example - you would want to handle LineUnavailable properly...
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException 
   {
      final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;            // Audio sampling rate
      final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2;                  // Audio sample size in bytes

      SourceDataLine line;
      double fFreq = 440;                         // Frequency of sine wave in hz

      //Position through the sine wave as a percentage (i.e. 0 to 1 is 0 to 2*PI)
      double fCyclePosition = 0;        

      //Open up audio output, using 44100hz sampling rate, 16 bit samples, mono, and big 
      // endian byte ordering
      AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(SAMPLING_RATE, 16, 1, true, true);
      DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

      if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)){
         System.out.println("Line matching " + info + " is not supported.");
         throw new LineUnavailableException();
      }

      line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
      line.open(format);  
      line.start();

      // Make our buffer size match audio system's buffer
      ByteBuffer cBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(line.getBufferSize());   

      int ctSamplesTotal = SAMPLING_RATE*5;         // Output for roughly 5 seconds


      //On each pass main loop fills the available free space in the audio buffer
      //Main loop creates audio samples for sine wave, runs until we tell the thread to exit
      //Each sample is spaced 1/SAMPLING_RATE apart in time
      while (ctSamplesTotal>0) {
         double fCycleInc = fFreq/SAMPLING_RATE;  // Fraction of cycle between samples

         cBuf.clear();                            // Discard samples from previous pass

          // Figure out how many samples we can add
         int ctSamplesThisPass = line.available()/SAMPLE_SIZE;   
         for (int i=0; i < ctSamplesThisPass; i++) {
            cBuf.putShort((short)(Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(2*Math.PI * fCyclePosition)));

            fCyclePosition += fCycleInc;
            if (fCyclePosition > 1)
               fCyclePosition -= 1;
         }

         //Write sine samples to the line buffer.  If the audio buffer is full, this will 
         // block until there is room (we never write more samples than buffer will hold)
         line.write(cBuf.array(), 0, cBuf.position());            
         ctSamplesTotal -= ctSamplesThisPass;     // Update total number of samples written 

         //Wait until the buffer is at least half empty  before we add more
         while (line.getBufferSize()/2 < line.available())   
            Thread.sleep(1);                                             
      }


      //Done playing the whole waveform, now wait until the queued samples finish 
      //playing, then clean up and exit
      line.drain();                                         
      line.close();
   }
}
```

It runs fine on Windows 10, and generates the sound perfectly. However on my Macbook Pro I get this error:

```
2015-11-17 11:20:16.549 java[5899:9037084] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2015-11-17 11:20:16.549 java[5899:9037084] Cannot find function pointer New_SHP_PlugIn for factory 834FC054-C1CC-11D6-BD01-00039315CD46 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fd672c25910 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-17 11:20:16.580 java[5899:9037084] 11:20:16.580 WARNING:  >compload> 472: Kickstart.component -- file://localhost/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/: trouble parsing Info.plist's AudioComponents, key (null); entry: <CFBasicHash 0x7fd67521c3f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff730e39f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "manufacturer"} = <CFString 0x7fd675231660 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "CaNR"}
    7 : <CFString 0x7fff730e74b0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "factoryFunction"} = <CFString 0x7fd6752319f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "KickstartAUFactory"}
    8 : <CFString 0x7fd675230f10 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "subtype"} = <CFString 0x7fd675230f50 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "CNKS"}
    9 : <CFString 0x7fff7310b6f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0x7fd67520fa20 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Kickstart"}
    10 : <CFString 0x7fff7310a3d0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7fd675231030 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "kAudioUnitType_Effect"}
    11 : <CFString 0x7fff73095bb0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x7fd675231630 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Nicky Romero: Kickstart"}
    12 : <CFString 0x7fff73114370 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "version"} = <CFNumber 0x1000937 [0x7fff73159390]>{value = +65545, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}
2015-11-17 11:20:16.586 java[5899:9037084] 11:20:16.586 WARNING:  >compload> 472: Primer.component -- file://localhost/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/: trouble parsing Info.plist's AudioComponents, key (null); entry: <CFBasicHash 0x7fd672c2dc50 [0x7fff73159390]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff730e39f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "manufacturer"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2e720 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "AudG"}
    7 : <CFString 0x7fff730e74b0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "factoryFunction"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2e8a0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "PrimerAUFactory"}
    8 : <CFString 0x7fd672c2e9d0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "subtype"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2ea10 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "agp"}
    9 : <CFString 0x7fff7310b6f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2c4a0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Primer"}
    10 : <CFString 0x7fff7310a3d0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2ec50 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "aumu"}
    11 : <CFString 0x7fff73095bb0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x7fd672c2e900 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Audible Genius: Primer"}
    12 : <CFString 0x7fff73114370 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "version"} = <CFNumber 0x1010137 [0x7fff73159390]>{value = +65793, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}
```

I don't understand this error at all. The only thing I know is that it is accessing my audio plugins. I also know the error occurs at:

```
line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
      line.open(format);
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this error is? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to try out: Open the line with default settings in both contexts and inspect the formats. The code you wrote may be objecting, for example, if the format you hard-coded is not supported.

To open with defaults, omit the arguments to the **line.open()** method. To get the format, use the method **line.getFormat()**. You can also test that the line works by playing back a wav file on the different OS's. If wavs play back okay, use the same format in your tutorial code.

The main reason I'm suggesting this is that I am surprised to see *BigEndian* being used as part of the format. I've always used *LittleEndian*.

If the default is stereo, you should be able to make and use an identical format with mono being the only difference, so that you don't have to modify the rest of the code.

However, there are some differences in the rest of the code that I kind of question. I wrote and use the following basic form for sending normalized PCM audio data to Java desktops:

```
float[] normalizedOut = float[2];
byte[] buffer = new byte[outBufferSize];
int i;

while(playing)
{
    i = 0;
    while(i < outBufferSize)
    {
        // obtain normalized, stereo PCM output from synth
        normalizedOut = synth.getNextFrame();

        // convert normalized to stereo bytes, "CD quality"
        normalizedOut[0] *= 32767;
        normalizedOut[1] *= 32767;
        // this part converts to Little Endian
        outBuffer[i++] = (byte) normalizedOut[0];
        outBuffer[i++] = (byte)((int)normalizedOut[0] >> 8);            
        outBuffer[i++] = (byte) normalizedOut[1];
        outBuffer[i++] = (byte)((int)normalizedOut[1] >> 8 );
    }
    line.write(outBuffer, 0, outBufferSize);
}
```

I think it is perfectly okay to allow Java to handle the blocking. The system will end up spending something like 98% (wild-assed guess) blocking on this thread unless your "synth" algo is really heavy duty.

The above loops one frame at a time. It would probably perform a bit better to obtain the sine data in larger chunks, but I like the simplicity of the above. Also, it seems to perform "good enough." For example, you can download and try an implementation I wrote that includes the above which employs 6 FM synthesizers (each employing multiple sines as carriers and modulators) all playing at once.

[circlesounds.jar demo](http://www.java-gaming.org/user-generated-content/members/27722/circlesounds.jar)
(Uses Java 8. Which reminds me, there are some older version of Mac OS have do not support some versions of Java. I recall a friend with a Mac laptop that couldn't run Java 7 programs I wanted him to try out. I am not up on the history of this.)